# Extract multiple TimeUnits from a String

Tags: java, timeunit

I am trying to strip every Time Unit of a String, e.g.

The String "4w10d50m39s" would return a TimeUnit of 4 weeks, a TimeUnit of 10 days, a TimeUnit of 50 minutes, and a TimeUnit of 39 seconds.

How can I achieve this?

Context: I need them to sum all the Time unit converted to millis and use it as a time stamp, it will be used inside a Minecraft server, in a command made to add a rank to a user for an specific amount of time, example: /addrank iLalox Vip 4w5d, that would set the expiration date to: `System.currentMillis() + timeInMillis`.

Comment: Apparently a follow-up question to [Convert String containing multiple time segments to millis \[closed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68789980/convert-string-containing-multiple-time-segments-to-millis).

Comment: I think we can help you more precisely is you tell us what you need those time units for. My first approach would be to parse into a `Period` and a `Duration` (or a ThreeTen Extra `PeriodDuration`). `Period` does not distinguish between 1 week and 7 days. Would it be a requirement to do that? `Duration` does not distinguish between 0 hours and hours not being present at all. Do you need such a distinction?

Comment: Can we exclude the possibility of any months being in the string? Asking because otherwise I wouldn’t know whether `3m` would mean 3 months or 3 minutes.

Comment: I suggest you educate the publisher of your data about the [ISO 8601 standard format for durations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

Comment: I need them to sum all the Time unit converted to millis and use it as a time stamp, it will be used inside a Minecraft server, in a command made to add a rank to a user for an specific amount of time, example: /addrank iLalox Vip 4w5d, that would set the expiration date to: System.currentMillis() + timeInMillis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract unit you can use regex

```
\\d+[wdms]
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NvY2aE/1)

Then you can use `matcher` to extract matches from string and create `TimeUnit`s. There is no `Week` constant in [`TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html), so i would present week as `amount of weeks * 7` in days.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = new String("4w10d50m39s");
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+[wdms]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);

    while(matcher.find()) {
        String unit = matcher.group();
        char timeType = unit.charAt(unit.length() - 1);
        int timeAmount = Integer.parseInt(unit.substring(0, unit.length() - 1));
        if(timeType == 'd') {
            System.out.println(TimeUnit.DAYS.toDays(timeAmount) + " DAYS");
        }

        if(timeType == 'm') {
            System.out.println(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMinutes(timeAmount) + " MINUTES");
        }

        if(timeType == 's') {
            System.out.println(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(timeAmount) + " SECONDS");
        }

        if(timeType == 'w') {
            System.out.println(TimeUnit.DAYS.toDays(timeAmount * 7L) + " DAYS IN WEEK");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
28 DAYS IN WEEK
10 DAYS
50 MINUTES
39 SECONDS
```

Comment: If using Java 12 or later, a [switch expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/language/switch-expressions.html) wold probably be useful here. Just guessing, one would also be interested in recognizing `h` for hours.

Comment: I think adding hours recognition is not that difficult over a template. By the way, do you think it would be appropriate here to create an enum for the time types.

Comment: So what you are saying, @user16320675, is that `ChronoUnit` is a better choice for enum than both `TimeUnit` and one we create ourselves? Correct? I think that it’s a good point.

Answer (score 1):

### Period, Duration and Instant from java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. Assuming your expiration is in real time (not Minecraft time):

```
    String string = "4w10d50m39s";
     
    String dayBasedString
            = string.replaceFirst("(^(?:\\d+w)?(?:\\d+d)?).*$", "$1");
    String timeBasedString = string.substring(dayBasedString.length());

    Period period = dayBasedString.isEmpty()
            ? Period.ZERO
            : Period.parse("P" + dayBasedString);
    assert period.getYears() == 0 : period;
    assert period.getMonths() == 0 : period;

    Duration dur = timeBasedString.isEmpty()
            ? Duration.ZERO
            : Duration.parse("PT" + timeBasedString); 
    dur = Duration.ofDays(period.getDays()).plus(dur);
    
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    Instant expiration = now.plus(dur);
    
    System.out.format("Now: %s; expiration: %s%n", now, expiration);
```

Output when I ran the snippet just now:

> Now: 2021-08-20T18:24:35.701136Z; expiration:
> 2021-09-27T19:15:14.701136Z

Java has classes `Period` for day-based periods and `Duration` for time-based ones. Since your string is both, I am using both classes. And the `Instant` class for a point in time like the expiration time of your rank.

The `Period` class can natively parse a String like `P4w10d`, and the `Duration` class one like `PT50m39s`. The challenge is to split your string after the weeks and days and before the hours, minutes and seconds. My regular expression matches any (possibly empty) part of the string containing weeks and/or days and copies this part to a separate variable. Then copying the rest to another variable is not so complicated. A `Period` may contain years, months and days (weeks are automatically converted to days). For my following calculation to work I need to assume that there were no years or months since I don’t know how many days those are. I am also assuming that a day is 24 hours even though this is not always the case in real life.

As a variation you may use a `ZonedDateTime` for the current time. The advantage will be that you can directly add first a `Period` and then a `Duration` to it without the need to convert the weeks and days to a `Duration` first. And as a further variation you may use the `PeriodDuration` class from the ThreeTen Extra project. I haven’t checked, but I would expect that it would be possible to add a `PeriodDuration` to a `ZonedDateTime` since it would make good sense.

> I need them to sum all the Time unit converted to millis and use it as
> a time stamp, …

For that you neither need to sum the units yourself nor to convert to milliseconds. `Period` and `Duration` parse larger chunks of your string, and `Instant.plus()` directly accepts the `Duration` object that we end up with.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [ThreeTen-Extra - Home](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/)